# AssertionError: Missing expected exception when testing async requirejs call using mocha

Tags: testing, requirejs, mocha.js, amd, node-assert

I'm writing a test for my custom requirejs loader. On malformed input it it supposed to throw an error.

I'm using `mocha` and plain `node-assert` to test it like this:

```
it('throws a SyntaxError on malformed input', function(done){
    assert.throws(function(){ requirejs(['myLoader!malformedInput'], Function.prototype) }, SyntaxError);
    done();
});
```

The test fails due to:

> AssertionError: Missing expected exception (SyntaxError)..

From what I understand [reading the docs on assert](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_block_error_message) my syntax should be ok. The error message is a little hard to understand too.

My best guess would be that this is due to the fact that the `requirejs` call is async, but then I don't know when to call `done` in this scenario?

Or am I misunderstanding something in the way that `requirejs` will handle the error that I pass to `onload.error(e)`?

Comment: Since node v10.0.0, `assert.rejects` has been addded for **async** assertion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`assert.throws` is not going to work for exceptions that are raised asynchronously. Here's an example of how it can be done using a RequireJS errback:

```js
var assert = require("assert");
var requirejs = require("requirejs");

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: ".",
});

it('throws a SyntaxError on malformed input', function (done){
    requirejs(['fail'], function (fail) {
        // This should not be called.
        throw new Error("We were expecting a failure but none occurred!");
    }, function (err) {
        assert(err.originalError instanceof SyntaxError,
                "We should get a SyntaxError.");
        done();
    });
});
```

The `fail.js` file should contain nonsensical code (i.e. that generates a `SyntaxError`). The second function passed to `requirejs` is an errback called when the load fails.

Comment: That's exactly how I ended up solving this, thank you!

Comment: @Louis. Thanks though i'm not using RequireJS. Was wondering why testing schema was failing with the async/ await. saw this and was able to understand. This is how i'm doing with async/await. Please let me know if doing it correctly or not though the test is passing?

`try {
            await user.save();
        } catch(err) {
            assert.equal(err.errors.email.message, 'Invalid Email');
        }`